# How to sort an array using bubble sort and swap the elements of an array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a project for work and I need some help. I'm able to pass one argument, multiple arguments, and all arguments, when the arguments are in order(CapA,CapB,etc.) but my function is useless whenever I try to pass the arguments out of order. Ex.(CapB,CapA) I know how to do it in C++, but I'm not sure how to do it in PowerShell. Please see the following code:

```
function Get-FieldOps
{
<#

.SYNOPSIS
Generates list of technicians for each Field Service Team.

.Description
Generates list of technicians for each Field Service Team.
It is able to generate a list of technicians for one team name, multiple team names, or all team names.

.Parameter Team
Team has to be a string variable or list of string variables. 

If value passed to team doesn't match a Field Service Team then it will error out.

.Example
Get-FieldOps -Team CapF

.Example
Get-FieldOps CapF

.NOTES

        Created on: 12/22/2021
        Created by: 
        FileName:
#>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String[]]$Team
    )

    $OTS_EUC_Field_Ops = @('CapA','CapB', 'CapC','CapD', 'CapE', 'CapF', 'Delivery', 'Network', 'NorthA', 'NorthB', 'NorthC', 'Projects', 'SouthA', 'SouthB', 'SouthC', 'SouthD')
    $OTS_Ivanti_Groups = @('_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2A','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2B','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2C','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2D','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2E', '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2F','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-Delivery','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-Network', '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-North-A','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-North-B','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-North-C','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-Projects-1361711097','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-A','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-B','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-C','_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-D')
    
    for($index=0;$index -lt $OTS_EUC_Field_Ops.Length;$index++)
    {

        if($Team[$index] -like $OTS_EUC_Field_Ops[$index])
        {
            Write-Host "************************************************"
            $OTS_EUC_Field_Ops[$index]
            Get-ADGroupMember $OTS_Ivanti_Groups[$index] |Format-Table -Property name,SamAccountName,distinguishedName -AutoSize
        }

        if($Team -like "ALL")
        {
            Write-Host "************************************************"
            $OTS_EUC_Field_Ops[$index]
            Get-ADGroupMember $OTS_Ivanti_Groups[$index] |Format-Table -Property name,SamAccountName,distinguishedName -AutoSize
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hashtable (an unordered associative array) instead of 3 arrays - this way you don't need to worry about alignment between the user input and the existing mapping between team names and group names:

```
# Define mapping
$FieldTeamGroupMapping = @{
    'CapA' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2A'
    'CapB' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2B'
    'CapC' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2C'
    'CapD' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2D'
    'CapE' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2E'
    'CapF' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2F'
    'Delivery' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-Delivery'
    'Network' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-Network'
    'NorthA' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-North-A'
    'NorthB' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-North-B'
    'NorthC' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-North-C'
    'Projects' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-Projects-1361711097'
    'SouthA' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-A'
    'SouthB' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-B'
    'SouthC' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-C'
    'SouthD' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-D'
}

if($Team -contains 'ALL'){
  # If the user specified `ALL`, resolve all team names
  $Team = $FieldTeamGroupMapping.Keys
}

# Loop over list of team names and do operations
foreach($teamName in $Team){
  if(-not $FieldTeamGroupMapping.ContainsKey($teamName)){
    Write-Error "Team name '$teamName' is not recognized"
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "************************************************"
    $teamName
    Get-ADGroupMember $FieldTeamGroupMapping[$teamName] |Format-Table -Property name,SamAccountName,distinguishedName -AutoSize
  }
}
```